# C++ inheritance not working on stack?

Tags: c++, inheritance, stack, virtual, new-operator

This is a down-sized problem of a much larger code. I know C.a should be on the heap but I want to avoid changing "." to "->" everywhere in the code. Is there a way I can circumvent this bug? (compiler is g++ 4.6.1)
I consider this a bug since c++ allows it but does not behave appropriately...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class AA {
public:
    virtual void foo() {
        cout << "AA!\n";
    };
};

class AB : public AA {
public:
    AB() : AA() { cout << "construct AB!\n"; }

    void foo() {
        cout << "AB!\n";
    }
};

class C {
public:
    AA a;
    void xchg() {
        a.~AA();
        new (&a) AB();  // everything works here except virtuals
    }
};

int main() {
    C c;
    c.a.foo(); // -> AA
    c.xchg();
    c.a.foo(); // -> AA :(

    AA *aa = new AB();
    aa->foo(); // -> AB (virtual works)

    return 0;
};
```

Comment: if your desire is just to use . instead of -> why not just use a reference?  Create the object on the heap, and then when you want to work with it, just assign it to a local reference.

Comment: Nerdtron, this wouldn't work in a class. 
AA *_a;AA &a = *_a;
Now _a needs to be const.

Comment: @chuu79: Why wouldn't that work?  Yes, `_a` can't point to a different memory location, but a new object can be created at that location.  On the other hand, it's still illegal to change type.  Just answered a question about that last week.

Answer (score 1):

The only bug is in your code.  You are invoking undefined behavior (in several different ways, actually).

The Standard does not require a diagnostic for this, it's not the compiler's responsibility to make sure you don't do anything stupid.

Comment: hmm too bad! kind of sad that the compiler is unable to block write access to stack pointers...

Comment: @chuu79: What stack pointer?  And why should access to the stack be blocked?  You've got a very unusual (and wrong) way of thinking about this.

Answer (score 1):

```
new (&a) AB();  // everything works here except virtuals
```

This doesn't really work:  the behavior here is undefined.  `a` is an object of type `AA`.  You cannot construct an object of type `AB` in its place.  The only kind of object you are permitted to construct there is an `AA` object.

If you need polymorphic behavior for `a`, you should use a pointer to a dynamically allocated object.  Preferably, a smart pointer to a dynamically allocated object, e.g., a `std::unique_ptr<AA>`.  Note also that `AA` should have a virtual destructor.